# Stopping an array after "__' rows and '___' columns in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, row

I'm completely frozen on this subject of arrays that is probably extremely simple to understand, but my brain is not comprehending it. Every video I find, every website I find, EVERYTHING about arrays never mentions a method on how to do it with random numbers rather than a fixed set of numbers.

So now I have this as part of a project and this is only the first part, can't wait to get further -_-

The code I'm writing is suppose to fill an array with random numbers from 1-999 in a grid of 10 columns, with 5 rows. I put this code in and it just goes on for 999 numbers until it stops. I cannot, for my life, figure out the way to stop it after said rows and columns.

```html
int main(){
 int arr[999];
 int i;
 
 for( i = 0; i < 999; i++){
  arr[i] = rand() % 999;
 }
 
 for( i = 0; i < 999; i++){
  printf("%d", arr[i]);
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

I know I have nothing about the rows and columns now in the code because I don't want to embarrass myself with the stuff I've tried. I'm hoping somebody can show me what to do. I understand the basics of the array, how to find a certain point in the array, but that is all for fixed numbers. And from what I've hunted down for hours, I can't find a darn thing.

Edit for @Kaylum:

The code that I have now is most likely not what you were telling me to try but:

```html
int main(){
 int arr[5][10];
 int i;
 
 for( i = 0; i < 5/10; i++){
  arr[i] = rand() % 999;
 }
 
 for( i = 0; i < 5/10; i++){
  printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `999` to `rows * columns`?

Comment: @kaylum on which part?

Comment: All of them. That is, wherever `999` appears replace with `rows * columns`. An alternative if you feel like trying is to use a double array: `int arr[rows][columns];` and then have two indexes which iterate from `0` to `rows/columns`. That would arguably be the more natural way to do it rather than a single flat array.

Comment: @kaylum I tried that but it comes up as an error stating "array type 'int [10]' is not assignable"

Comment: No you didn't try "that". You tried some code which I can't see and can't comment on. Please update your question if you want help on something new.

Comment: May I suggest you go through a systematic tutorial on C and arrays. It's obvious that you have not understood even the basic syntax. Not meaning to put you down just trying to suggest that trying to learn such basics via SO questions is not productive for you or for others. Arrays require a subscript per dimension. So your first for loop should be: `for(row = 0; row < 5; row++) { for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) arr[row][column] = rand() % (5 * 10); }`

Comment: @KyleSteward Has this question been answered, or is the provided answer not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have misunderstood a thing or two about arrays. Let me try to explain:

If you are trying to fill a one dimensional array of length `n` with random numbers (in the range of 0 - 999), you would have to loop over every entry in the array and assign it a random number. That would mean you have too loop over n entries like this:

```
int your_array[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    your_array[i] = rand() % 1000;
}
```

Note: Array indexing starts at 0! So if you have an array of length `n`, the last entry is going to be at `your_array[n - 1]`, not `your_array[n]`.

---

Now, you are trying to fill a two-dimensional array. This is basically not much different than an array in one dimension. If you try to picture it visually, you have a grid of 5 rows and 10 columns. This is in other words nothing else but 5 one-dimensional arrays of size 10, arranged on top of each other. This means you have to do the same thing as above, just for every one of the 5 rows. In code this looks something like this:

```
int rows = 5;
int cols = 10;
int your_array[rows][cols];

// Loop over all rows.
for(int current_row = 0; current_row < rows; current_row++){
    // On each row, loop over all columns.
    for(int current_col = 0; current_col < cols; current_col++){
        your_array[current_row][current_col] = rand() % 1000;
    }
}
```

Does this clear things up a bit? 
If you have any questions, let me know.

---

Addendum: If you want to generate a random number in the range of 0 to and *including* 999, you have to get it with `n = rand() % 1000`, instead of `n = rand() % 999`, because the modulus of any number `x` divided by and number `y`, can only be in the range `[0, y - 1]`.